# Extract tag from cipher aes 256 GCM Golang

Tags: ruby, go, aes-gcm

I have encryption and decryption in Ruby and try to rewrite with Go. I try step by step, so start with encryption in ruby and try to decryption in go, it's works. But when I try to write [encryption](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewGCM) in Go and decrypt in ruby. I'm stuck when try to extract the tag, I explain the reason why I need extract the auth tag

Encryption In ruby

```
plaintext = "Foo bar"
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.iv = iv # string 12 len
cipher.key = key # string 32 len
cipher.auth_data = # string 12 len
cipherText = cipher.update(JSON.generate({value: plaintext})) + cipher.final
authTag = cipher.auth_tag
hexString = (iv + cipherText + authTag).unpack('H*').first
```

I try to concatenate an initial vector, a ciphertext and the authentication tag, so before decrypt I can extract them, especially the authentication tag, because I need set it before calling Cipher#final in Ruby

[auth_tag](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-auth_tag)

> The tag must be set after calling Cipher#decrypt, Cipher#key= and
> Cipher#iv=, but before calling Cipher#final. After all decryption is
> performed, the tag is verified automatically in the call to
> Cipher#final

Here is function encryption in golang

```
ciphertext := aesgcm.Seal(nil, []byte(iv), []byte(plaintext), []byte(authData))
src := iv + string(ciphertext) // + try to add authentication tag here
fmt.Printf(hex.EncodeToString([]byte(src)))
```

How can I extract the authentication tag and concatenate it with iv and ciphertext, so I can decrypt with decryption function in ruby

```
raw_data = [hexString].pack('H*')
cipher_text = raw_data.slice(12, raw_data.length - 28)
auth_tag = raw_data.slice(raw_data.length - 16, 16)

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm').decrypt
cipher.iv = iv # string 12 len
cipher.key = key # string 32 len
cipher.auth_data = # string 12 len
cipher.auth_tag = auth_tag
JSON.parse(cipher.update(cipher_text) + cipher.final)
```

I want to be able doing encryption in Go, and try to decryption in Ruby.

Comment: Can you clarify your ultimate goal? At the start you state `I have encryption and decryption in Ruby and try to rewrite with Go.` - but at the end you want to `decrypt with decryption function in ruby`.  Are you encrypting on the `go` side - and then want to decrypt in the `ruby` end?

Comment: @colm.anseo yes.. if you see I told about step by step, I mean I can't do with big bang process, so I have successfully to use ruby for encrypt and use go for decrypt, and I want to try inverse of that, use go for encrypt and use ruby for decypt in the exact time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your encryption flow to be something like this:

```
func encrypt(in []byte, key []byte) (out []byte, err error) {

    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        return
    }

    out = gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, in, nil) // include the nonce in the preable of 'out'
    return
}
```

Your input `key` should be of 16, 24 or 32 bytes in length as per [aes.NewCipher](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/aes/#NewCipher) docs.

The encrypted `out` bytes from the above function will include the `nonce` prefix (16, 24 or 32 bytes in length) - so it can be easily extracted during the decryption stage like so:

```
// `in` here is ciphertext
nonce, ciphertext := in[:ns], in[ns:]
```

where `ns` is computed like so:

```
c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    return
}

gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
if err != nil {
    return
}

ns := gcm.NonceSize()
if len(in) < ns {
    err = fmt.Errorf("missing nonce - input shorter than %d bytes", ns)
    return
}
```

---

***EDIT***:

If you are encrypting on the `go` side with defaults cipher settings (see above):

```
gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
```

from [the source](https://golang.org/src/crypto/cipher/gcm.go#L154) the tag byte-size will be `16`.

Note: if [cipher.NewGCMWithTagSize](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#NewGCMWithTagSize) is used - then the size will obviously be different (basically anywhere between `12` to `16` bytes)

So lets assume the tag size is `16`, armed with this knowledge, and knowing the full payload arrangement is:

```
IV/nonce + raw_ciphertext + auth_tag
```

the `auth_tag` on the `Ruby` side for decryption, is the final 16 bytes of the payload; and the raw_ciphertext is all bytes after the `IV/nonce` up until where the `auth_tag` begins.

Comment: thank you, but how can I extract the tag? it seems that prepend the vector, if you see decryption in ruby, I need the tag to verify before calling cipher final, I can't find any reference in golang to extract the tag, and I think the tag is automatically append to cipher text  in golang

Comment: The auth tags are implicited added during encryption and verified during decryption. There's no need for the caller to do this, the `cipher` package does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: absolutly I'm seeing in Golang we don't need that, but when I decrypt in ruby, you can see that needed for verification

Comment: you mean I just extract with slice cipher_text with size 16 bytes

Comment: the cipher_text is variable length - but the `nonce/IV` and `auth_tag` are fixed (or agreed upon at encyption type). Since they sandwich the `cipher_text` its easy to compute when looking at the entire payload length. I've update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

`aesgcm.Seal` automatically appends the GCM tag at the end of the ciphertext. You can see it in the [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4e8badbbc2fe7854bb1c12a9ee42315b4d535051/src/crypto/cipher/gcm.go#L190):

```
    var tag [gcmTagSize]byte
    g.auth(tag[:], out[:len(plaintext)], data, &tagMask)
    copy(out[len(plaintext):], tag[:])                   // <---------------- here
```

So you're done, you don't need anything else. `gcm.Seal` already returns the ciphertext with the auth tag appended at the end.

Similarly you don't need to extract the auth tag for `gcm.Open`, it does it automatically, [too](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4e8badbbc2fe7854bb1c12a9ee42315b4d535051/src/crypto/cipher/gcm.go#L214):

```
    tag := ciphertext[len(ciphertext)-g.tagSize:]        // <---------------- here
    ciphertext = ciphertext[:len(ciphertext)-g.tagSize]
```

So all you have to do during decryption is to extract the IV (nonce) and pass the rest in as ciphertext.

Comment: I thank you for explaining in detail, of couse I know if I use Go for decryption I don't need to exact the auth tag, but my case is I use Go with encryption and use Ruby for decryption, in Ruby I need to set auth tag before cipher final, so I need to exact the auth tag in Go and concatenate it with cipher

Comment: You don't need to extract the auth tag in Go. You need to extract the auth tag in Ruby. And your Ruby code already does that: `auth_tag = raw_data.slice(raw_data.length - 16, 16)`. The tag will be there, Go puts it there automatically.